# Fetch() request immediately failing in service worker running through Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, service-worker, fetch-api

I have a service worker that I use to enable an offline version of my website. This works great. I also have an Android app that is basically just a wrapper around a webview that loads my website.

All was fine and dandy until about 2-3 weeks ago when the Fetch() request started immediately failing. It is only failing when running through the Android webview. Running through a browser works fine. If the resource is cached already (i.e. via the install event) then it works great, it's only when I get a page that is not cached.

The code in my service worker:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {

if (event.request.method !== 'GET'
    || event.request.url.toLowerCase().indexOf('//ws') > -1
    || event.request.url.toLowerCase().indexOf('localws') > -1) {
    // Don't intercept requests made to the web service
    // If we don't block the event as shown below, then the request will go to
    // the network as usual.

    return;
}


event.respondWith(async function () {
    // override the default behavior

    var oCache = await caches.open('cp_' + version);
    var cached = await oCache.match(event.request.url);

    if (cached && cached.status < 300) {
        return cached;
    }

    // Need to make a call to the network
    try {
        var oResp = await fetch(event.request); // THIS LINE CAUSES THE PROBLEM!!!
        return oResp;
    } catch (oError) {
        console.log('SW WORKER: fetch request to network failed.', event.request);


        return new Response('<h1>Offline_sw.js: An error has occured. Please try again.</h1><br><h2>Could not load URL: ' + event.request.url + '</h2>', {
            status: 503,
            statusText: 'Service Unavailable',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'text/html'
            })
        });
    }  
}()); // event.respondwith
}); // fetch
```

The line:

> var oResp = await fetch(event.request);

is called once I've determined it is not cached and seems to be the culprit. When it errors out I get the following error in my catch(): 'Failed to fetch'

[image: Fetch Error Message]

This seems pretty generic and not helpful. Again, this works when going through a browser and so I know it's not a CORS issue, service worker in the wrong directory, etc. Again, it worked until about 3 weeks ago and now I'm getting reports from customers that it's not working.

Here's a screen shot of the actual event.request that I'm sending off:

[image: event.request object]

In the chrome developer tools (used to debug the webview) I see the following:

[image: Dev Tools Screen SHot]

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the webview / chrome that was released recently? (I say that as chrome powers the webview)

Comment: NEVER post code, errors or output as images! [mcve]

Comment: @Rob I typed the error and then posted a screen shot of it in case that made it clearer to anyone. On the Request object, all properties are read only and I'm only intercepting it in the service worker so I didn't see another good way to display the info.

Comment: Looks like this may be a chromium bug. Waiting to see for sure before I mark this question answered. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=977784

Comment: @ScottR yup, your symptoms exactly match my bug :D  You should be able to verify by downloading the Chrome 76 beta and using the developer setting to switch the system webview - I wasn't seeing the bug in the 76 webview.

Comment: @Rowan Glad to hear it seems to be fixed in the beta. How do I download the Chrome 76 beta? Is that just Chrome Beta in the play store? Do I need to side load it?

Comment: @ScottR Oops, belatedly: yes, just Chrome Beta in the play store. On Android 7+ you can then go to Settings > Developer Options > Webview implementation to choose it; more complete instructions at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/android_webview/docs/prerelease.md .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug in chromium. See bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=977784. Should be fixed in v 76.

As a work around (as the link mentioned), you can add the following to your android code:

```
ServiceWorkerController oSWController = null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
        oSWController = ServiceWorkerController.getInstance();
        oSWController.setServiceWorkerClient(new ServiceWorkerClient(){
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebResourceRequest request){
                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(request);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I have the same problem in chrome, and I can change my users android code.
what should I do in that case? the service workers not working well in android and I am getting error for my fetch request